# MonetDB bulk load with auto increment

Tags: csv, auto-increment, monetdb, bulk-load

I am trying to load csv files into monetdb table(s) with auto increment PK/Id columns using `copy into <table> from file...`.

1. table has auto increment PK column.
2. table has more columns than incoming csv files.
3. csv file doesnt have Pk/Id column.

Is there a way to specify columns while loading data? something like
`Copy into <tableName>( col2, col2,...) from file ...`?

For (1), the work around I have found is to drop the auto increment pk/id column and alter table later.
For (2) load file into a temp table and insert/update actual table later. Though its getting cumbersome, not to mention overhead of insert/update instead of bulk load.

Any help/pointer would be really appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You are right, [the monetdb doc](https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/Manuals/SQLreference/CopyInto) doesn't mention a way to specify in which columns to insert the data read from CSV file.
However, to achieve this, you can use a temporary table followed by a 'INSERT INTO' with a select subquery  :

1. Import your data into a temporary table 'tmp'
2. Run `INSERT INTO <table>(<col1>, <col2>, ...) SELECT <col1>, <col2>, ... FROM tmp`

The "insert into" from a subquery will be equivalent to a bulk insert, and should be quite fast.

Comment: An advance and mature database engine doesn't allow to import auto increment columns?

Comment: You are right, an advanced and mature database engine should allow to import auto increment columns. But MoneyDB is more like a R&D tool. For production environment, HP Vertica or Amazon Redshift may be more appropriate (and also more costly).

Answer (score 2):

The solution depends mostly on the format of the csv file so let's take a look at an example.

The **csv file contains a header line** and is separated with commas (mind that the `monetdb` **default field delimiter is** `'|'`).

> # cat /path/to/file.csv
> val1, val2, val3
> asd,2,23
> dsa,3,24

```
sql>CREATE TABLE example (id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, val1 VARCHAR(30),val2 INT, val3 INT);
sql>COPY OFFSET 2 INTO example (val1, val2, val3) FROM '/path/to/file.csv' (val1, val2, val3) DELIMITERS ',';
```

1. `OFFSET 2` makes sure that the header is not copied to the table.
2. `example (val1, val2, val3) FROM '/path/to/file.csv' (val1, val2, val3)` part is needed as we don't want to copy value for `id` column.
3. `DELIMITERS ','` is a must as the default field delimiter is '|'.

For further details see https://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/ServerAdministration/LoadingBulkData